# Series and sequences: Exercise

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sum the serie $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln [1+\dfrac{1}{k(k+2)}]$$ How can that be added

Comment: Telescopically.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** This telescopes. You should get
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln \left( 1+ \frac{1}{k(k+2)}\right) = \ln \left(\frac{2(n+1)}{n+2} \right)$$